# Libraries/languages to create animations in web-based game

Tags: web-development, css, game-development, animation

I am working on a quiz game and I would like to create more interesting views than just just showing static lists and questions. Could anyone tell me what languages/libraries I could use to create animations and/or moving elements to spice up the layout. I could use CSS3 transitions but there have to be other tools available too.

I like this example using css3 animations: http://bennettfeely.com/csscreatures/

update:

With animations, I am referring to moving backgrounds and bouncing, rotating, fading or resizing scene objects like: user avatars, buttons (on click) and  text on the screen.

Comment: What kind of animations? People should not have to click on links, the question must be understandable on its own. Cheers!

Comment: You could use css3 animations. W3 has a page on this. You could also use a library like flash or use a js library. I have done a few animations with css before and they work beautifully.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am alslo looking into [phaser](http://phaser.io/) now (game library)